# Tabify 3 QDockWidget

Tags: c++, qt5, qmainwindow, qdockwidget

How can I create a tabified dock for 3 widgets in QMainWindow?

I'm using the code bellow:

```
widget1 = new QDockWidget(this);
widget1 ->setObjectName("name1");
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, widget1);
widget2 = new QDockWidget(this);
widget2 ->setObjectName("name2");
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, widget2);
tabifyDockWidget(widget2, widget1);
widget3 = new QDockWidget(this);
widget3->setObjectName("name3");
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, widget3);
tabifyDockWidget(widget3, widget1);
```

This code is resulting in two docks: Dock 2 alone, and Dock 1 and 3 tabified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fix, I just change the position of first and second parameters:

```
widget1 = new QDockWidget(this);
widget1 ->setObjectName("name1");
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, widget1);

widget2 = new QDockWidget(this);
widget2 ->setObjectName("name2");
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, widget2);
tabifyDockWidget(widget2, widget1);

widget3 = new QDockWidget(this);
widget3->setObjectName("name3");
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, widget3);
tabifyDockWidget(widget1, widget3);
```